# How do I add a class name to Javascript string?

Tags: javascript, classname

I'm a JS newbie trying to alter the following code. It looks like it's adding style attributes. I would like to add the class name "reveal" to this string or below. What would that syntax look like? Many thanks for your help, guys!

```
 inline = ( elem.domEl.getAttribute( 'style' ) ) ? elem.domEl.getAttribute( 'style' ) + 
'; visibility: visible; ' : 'visibility: visible; '
```

Comment: This is a ternary condition - if the `style` attribute exists, assign the style attribute + `visibility: visible;`, else, just return `visibility:visible`. You can't add a class to this.\

Comment: I think he is talking about the DOM element at `elem.domE1` which seems to exist according to his provided code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I guess) the HTML may look like this:

```
<div class="some other">
```

In such case, if you do it like

```
elem.domEl.className = 'reveal';
```

then you'll get

```
<div class="reveal">
```

All styles brought by class **some** and **other** are gone! You definitely don't want that, right? Also you don't want repeated classname, something like

```
<div class="reveal reveal">
```

### So, here are the solutions:

The best way is to use HTML5 API `classList`:

```
elem.domEl.classList.contains('reveal') // Check whether element has a classname
elem.domEl.classList.add('reveal') // Add a classname
elem.domEl.classList.remove('reveal') // Remove a classname
elem.domEl.classList.toggle('reveal') // Toggle a classname
```

If you still want to run the code in out-dated browsers, try these:

```
// Check whether element has a classname
function hasClass(ele, cls) {
    var clsChecker = new RegExp("\\b" + cls + "\\b");
    return clsChecker.test(ele.className);
}
// Add a classname
function addClass(ele, cls) {
    var clsChecker = new RegExp("\\b" + cls + "\\b");
    if(clsChecker.test(ele.className)) {
        // ele already has the className, don't need to do anything
        return;
    }
    ele.className += (' '+ cls);
}

// Remove a classname
function removeClass(ele, cls) {
    var clsChecker = new RegExp("\\b" + cls + "\\b");
    if(clsChecker.test(ele.className)) {
        // ele does have the className, remove them all (in case repeated)
        ele.className.split(clsChecker).join('');
    }
}

// Toggle a classname
function toggleClass(ele, cls) {
    var clsChecker = new RegExp("\\b" + cls + "\\b");
    if(clsChecker.test(ele.className)) {
        // ele does have the className, remove them all (in case repeated)
        ele.className.split(clsChecker).join('');
    } else {
        // ele doesn't have the classname, add it
        ele.className += (' '+ cls);
    }
}

// Usages
hasClass(elem.domEl, 'reveal') // Check whether element has a classname
addClass(elem.domEl, 'reveal') // Add a classname
removeClass(elem.domEl, 'reveal') // Remove a classname
toggleClass(elem.domEl, 'reveal') // Toggle a classname
```

Comment: This is awesome! Many thanks! Is there a way to slightly delay the .classList function?

Comment: What do you mean by slightly delay? I didn't get the question, can you please describe the purpose?

Comment: Basically this function is adding visibility:visible and the class reveal to the element at the same time. I would like to add some time between each action so it animates to being visible, then animates with reveal attributes.

Comment: Then you should try opacity. Say, your element is a `<p>`, in CSS add these selectors `p {transition: opacity 500ms linear; opacity: 0;} .reveal {opacity: 1;}` Then toggle the classname `reveal`.

Comment: `transition` is the simplest way to achive animation in CSS. Using opacity, the element will fade in/out. Also you can try other properties, like using width/height to get shrink/scale effect, using transform to get fly in/out effect, etc.

Comment: Nice copy/paste answer!

Comment: @self I typed every letter with my fingers. Front-end development is my expertise. I don't have to copy paste because that's all in my mind. On the other hand, no offense, my answer is indeed better than yours.

Comment: Hi Leo. Thanks again for your contribution.

I do have a CSS transition for this class, but it is not working in pair with the JS. The JS plugin I am using, add styles to an element when it is visible in the viewport. Once the element in the viewport, rather than transitioning .reveal's attributes unto the element, the element appears with .reveal already added, thus with no transition.

This is why I would like the element to be visible as it, delay, then add .reveal so there is a transition from div to div.reveal. Does that make sense?

Comment: There's an event called 'transitionend', it is dispatched when a style transition is finished. You could listen to the event like this: `elem.domEl.addEventListener('transitionend', function(e) { /* things you want to do here */ })`.

Comment: And by the way, although `visibility` is an [animatable property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties), according to spec it's [interpolated as a discrete step](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animtype-visibility), so you wouldn't see *actual* animation. That's the reason I suggested `opacity`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it would be to just modify the [`Element.className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.className) property. If by saying "add class" you mean to push back a class name (string) to the element regardless of the current class name (string), then this code would do the job.

`elem.domEl.className = elem.domEl.className + ' ' + <YOUR_STRING_HERE>`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

`elem.domEl.setAttribute("class", "reveal");`

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
inline = ( elem.domEl.getAttribute( 'class' ) ) ? elem.domEl.getAttribute( 'class' ) + ' classname ' : 'classname '
```

Also this is possible:

```
var cls = elem.domEl.className;
elem.domEl.className = cls ? cls + ' classname' : 'classname';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write

```
inline = ( elem.domEl.getAttribute( 'style' ) ) ? elem.domEl.getAttribute( 'style' ) + '; visibility: visible; ' : 'visibility: visible; '

elem.domEl.className = "reveal";
```

The catch here is classname is not a style attribute, its an element property.

Answer (score 0):

May be you want to do like below:

```
inline = (elem.domEl.style.visibility == 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
```

But if you just want to set the visible css then do this way:

```
elem.domEl.style.visibility = 'visible';
```